# Sequence neither SELECT nor CREATE in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-sequence

I am facing a problem while using `sequence` in Oracle 11g Express Edition. It's neither accessible nor created.
I tried this query to get `NEXTVAL` of sequence.

```
select SEQ_PATIENT.nextval from dual;
```

It displays error

> ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Then I tried to `CREATE` the `SYNONYM` for above sequence as below

```
create synonym SEQ_PATIENT
for scott.SEQ_PATIENT;
```

and it returns

> ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Why is it so?

Comment: How about  `select scott.SEQ_PATIENT.nextval from dual;` ?

Comment: It doesn't make any effect at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
select SEQ_PATIENT.nextval from dual;
```

means that you want to select next value from a sequence whose name is SEQ_PATIENT and it belongs to current schema (i.e. the user you're connected to). Oracle says that you don't have that sequence.

---

This:

```
create synonym SEQ_PATIENT for scott.SEQ_PATIENT;
```

tries to create a **synonym** (**NOT** a sequence!) named SEQ_PATIENT for object whose name is SEQ_PATIENT which belongs to user Scott. Oracle says that object with name SEQ_PATIENT already exists.

So: how are you connected to the database? Which user is it?

What is the result of

```
select * from all_objects where object_name = 'SEQ_PATIENT';
```

It should tell you who owns it and what it is. Depending on its result, we'll be able to suggest further steps.

Answer (score 1):

I just used `DROP SYNONYM` and again used `CREATE` it worked fine.